# Unable to update changes using OData services

Tags: experience-manager, dxa

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
>
> An error occurred while processing this request.
>
> Storage not available: No Data Access Object Factory for defaultFile. Check if the default file system is properly defined and ItemTypes defaultStorageId is correct.

I am using a DXA java application. I have XPM up and able to edit a Component but I am not able to update preview. I have the XPM webservice configured and the XPM web application is separate from the staging website.

Comment: First verify your storage.config file of OData as this error usually comes when there is an issue with file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is on your `cd_storage_conf.xml`. It contains a defaultFile element but probably has no physical path set.

I suspect that you are pointing to a `defaultFile` location in an item type, i.e:

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile" />
```

but then there is no mapping to the physical location of the `defaultFile`.

If you check the standard `cd_storage_conf.xml` you will see this section

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false" >
    <Root Path="c:\temp" />
</Storage>
```

please ensure that this is present.

Besides this, it could be that the same is missing for the `defaultStorageId` location, where you might have this part:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFile" cached="false">
```

but missing again the physical path to this `defaultStorageId`.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I had commented the storage filesystem in the XPM webservice cd_storage_conf.xml.

Answer (score 3):

For DXA you should use database storage for every item as described in our documentation (here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51), so also your odata service should use this, in its `cd_storage_conf.xml` you need to specify that all Item Types will be stored in the database:

```xml
...
  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  </ItemTypes>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your storage configuration is correct (which it probably is not, see the two previous answers) this can be a problem with a missing or invalid license file (causing the storage subsystem to fall back to using file storage instead of database storage without throwing an error).